# Apache Kafka and Zookeeper connection problem

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a multi-node Apache Kafka cluster by using Docker swarm. To do that, I use the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
   zookeeper:
      image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
      ports:
         - "2181:2181"

   kafka:
      image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
      deploy:
         mode: global
      ports:
         - target: 9094
           published: 9094
           protocol: tcp
           mode: host
      environment:
         HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2" # Normal instances
         KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
         KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
         KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PROTOCOL_NAME: OUTSIDE
         KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9094
         KAFKA_PROTOCOL_NAME: INSIDE
         KAFKA_PORT: 9092
         KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: myTopic:1:1
      volumes:
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But, when kafka_kafka service is created, I encounter with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'PLAINTEXT://ugur:9094': No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:312)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.advertisedListeners(KafkaConfig.scala:1300)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1360)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1338)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1028)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1008)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:59)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$$anonfun$securityProtocol$1$1.apply(EndPoint.scala:48)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$$anonfun$securityProtocol$1$1.apply(EndPoint.scala:48)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.securityProtocol$1(EndPoint.scala:47)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.createEndPoint(EndPoint.scala:56)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anonfun$6.apply(CoreUtils.scala:309)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anonfun$6.apply(CoreUtils.scala:309)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
kafka_kafka.0.wx4chyussuuc@ugur    |    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:309)
```

I also open necessary ports, and these ports like that:

To                         Action      From

--                         ------      ----

9094                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9092                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8081                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2377                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
7946                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
4789                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9094 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9092 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8081 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2377 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
7946 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
4789 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

Comment: BTW, you'll also want to volume mount the zookeeper data and Kafka data, otherwise, you lose everything when the containers restart

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using using the docker-compose-swarm.yml available at GitHub?

https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/docker-compose-swarm.yml

Maybe the missing property bellow is the key:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following options:

```
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
  ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
```

Obviously plaintext listener is not secure but it should get you started.